# Small and thin GPS Transmitter

Tags: gps, tracking-devices

So, I asked [this](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/gps-transmitter-that-works-without-mobile-networks) question on IoT, and I'm here for something like that.

Basically, I need a small and thin GPS transmitter that is easily concealable between layers of cloth. There will be little to no mobile network, so something that stores data and sends it when networks are available would be preferable.

However, in addition to tracking, it is imperative that the device ***NOT*** be discovered. It must be concealed between layers of cloth, so it must be thin.

Comment: Being discovered will depend on the environment it is being used in and whether people are looking for it or not.

Comment: @RichardChambers People are not looking for it, but will be invariably cautious. Please see the linked questions and its commnets for additional details.